# C# file stream become close in thread

Tags: c#, filestream

```cs
main(string[] args) {
    string file = @"D:\123.txt";

    using (FileStream f = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        f.Position = 0;
        StartReadBookThread(f);
    }   
}
//this is a public API for user
public static Thread StartReadBookThread(Stream stream)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CanSeek:" + stream.CanSeek);
    var t = new Thread(() => DoReadBook(stream));
    t.Start();
    return t;
}

private static void DoReadBook(Stream stream)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CanSeek:" + stream.CanSeek);
}
```

In the `DoReadBook` method,the stream becomes closed, `CanSeek` becomes false.
How to handle it if I want to read the stream in a thread
the general way is we provide a public API  StartReadBookThread for user and it run in a thread .
user we always like call the parameter file stream in the suggest using(){} ... way.
so how can we read the file in a better way.
you know we just do it in a thread,sometimes it may get closed.

Comment: Why don't you open the stream in the thread?

Comment: Your whole code confuses me, if `CanSeek` is `false` then you'll get an exception on `f.Position = 0`, yet you're doing that first: before your check.

Comment: @John The stream is closed after `StartReadBookThread` returns, which is generally before `DoReadBook` runs.

Comment: @John I was only addressing your confusion about `f.Position = 0`, which works fine. CanSeek becomes false later.

Comment: StartReadBookThread is a public API

Comment: @difeijin How does that change anything? It's also `private` in your code.

Comment: @difeijin you want to process file in a seperate thread. Is this the only motive or stream getting disposed is the concern?

Comment: So you've designed a bad API. The way around it is to redesign it to make it a better API. For instance, you can have `public Task StartReadBookThread(Stream stream)`, use actual async stream reading methods inside it, without spawning new threads, and then your users would have `using (var f = File.Open(...)) { await StartReadBookThread(f);  }`. Failing that, you can document that your API assumes ownership of the stream and will close it when it's done with it, in which case you would have `using(stream)` inside `StartReadBookThread` and the caller would have removed it from their side.

Comment: you are right,yeha,
public Task StartReadBookThread(Stream stream) ,
using (var f = File.Open(...)) { await StartReadBookThread(f); }
this is better ,I just look for it

Answer (score 5):

Your stream is disposed when `StartReadBookThread` returns and you hit the `}` in your using statement in `main`.

Your workflow is basically:

1. Buy a lawn mower (`FileStream`).
2. Ask a worker to mow the lawn (`Thread`).
3. Immediately return the lawn mower (`using` statement).
4. Expect the worker to keep on mowing the lawn with a lawn mower you no longer have (wrong expectations).

Answer (score 0):

```
  using (FileStream f = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {

                   var stream = new MemoryStream();
                   f.Position = 0;
                   f.CopyTo(stream);
                    StartReadBookThread(stream );
        }
```

I'd like this code

Answer (score -1):

U need to wait on thread you are returning from function StartReadBookThread
Have look at updated code snippet.

```
    main(string[] args)
    {
        string file = @"D:\123.txt";

        using (FileStream f = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            f.Position = 0;
            var t = StartReadBookThread(f);
            t.Join(); // wait on the thread
        }
    }

    private static Thread StartReadBookThread(Stream stream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CanSeek:" + stream.CanSeek);
        var t = new Thread(() => DoReadBook(stream));
        t.Start();
        return t;
    }
```

Comment: What is the point of spawning a new thread only to immediately freeze the original thread? Might as well do the work on the original thread.

Comment: @GSerg yes you are correct, i provided a work around for his problem. I know this is not correct way to do process of stream. I know there are better ways of do the same.